# NextJS Webpack aliases on non-components files (.ts)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js, alias

I've been working on my Next JS config in order to be able to use 'Webpack Aliases' on it.

Basically, as the official documentation says, I've added the 'baseUrl' and the 'paths' on my **tsconfig.json**.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@layouts/*": ["layouts/*"],
      "@ui/*": ["ui/*"]
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

This works fine when I try to import some of those in any component file, like this:

```
// index.tsx
import Layout from '@layouts/default';
import Title from '@components/Title';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Title>I'm a stackoverflow example</Title>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

The problem comes when I try to import any file with his alias in a files that is not a 'tsx', for example, in a **'styles.ts'** that I use in order to create my css-in-js (using for example Styled-Components, emotion, linaria, etc..).

```
// ../styles.ts
import { styled } from '@linaria/react';
import { rems } from '@ui/helpers'; 

const Container = styled.h1`
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-weight: bold;

`;

export { Container };
```

In this case, this causes a crash:

> error - ./components/Title/styles.ts Error:
> D:\Documentos\Programming_Container\archetype-nextjs-linaria\components\Title\styles.ts:
> An unexpected runtime error occurred during dependencies evaluation:
> D:\Documentos\Programming_Container\archetype-nextjs-linaria\node_modules@linaria\webpack5-loader\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:246
> if (err) throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Can't resolve '@ui/helpers' in
> 'D:\Documentos\Programming_Container\archetype-nextjs-linaria\components\Title'
> It may happen when your code or third party module is invalid or uses
> identifiers not available in Node environment, eg. window.

I'm not sure how could I fix this.

Comment: What is the directory structure of `@ui/helpers` or is it a file? This isn't an issue with naming a file `.tsx` or `.ts`, `tsconfig.json` is applied to both cases. Hence, the aliases should have worked just fine.

Comment: @ui/helpers is a file -> ../ui/helpers.ts . Without using the aliases, the import is `import { rems } from './../../ui/helpers';`, and with this, it works fine.

Comment: It's in the same level of `/components`. In the example posted in the above comment, it goes two level up, because my `styles.ts` is inside `/components/Title/styles.ts`. Since `/ui` is at the same level of `/components`, I have to go two levels up `../../ui`.

Comment: It is an issue specific to `linaria`: https://github.com/callstack/linaria/issues/663